# "Missing Profile" message when opening files in Adobe Photoshop CS6

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I'm getting this message on almost every file I open with Photoshop CS6 (I had CS5.5 and this never happened).

Besides not being sure if any one of the options could screw up my file, which worries me a little bit, what is really lacking here is a "don't ask again" checkbox. It's becoming maddening, especially considering I do batch processing and it asks this for every file. what can I do?

[image: Missing Profile Screenshot]

**Missing Profile**

*The RGB document "X" has a file format that does not support embedded color profiles. What would you like to do?*

- Leave as is (don't color manage)
- Assign working RGB: ___
- Assign Profile: ___

  - [ ] and then convert document to working RGB

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'VE FOUND IT.

Edit > Color Settings. uncheck the "Ask When Opening" checkboxes at the bottom, in Color Management Policies.

[image: Color Settings]